# Is it possible getting into vegetative state by yourself?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, dreams

Had a very crazy and intense dream last night where I swapped between different stages of dream depth which actually also included dreaming about the actual place where I was sleeping within a dream within my dream.
I was really confused when I woke up about which stage was real and which wasn't. Somehow it made me wonder if it is possible to get stuck within your own dreams and getting into a state of vegetativeness by yourself this way?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE!  What is your definition of a vegetative state?

Comment: Thanks. :) Like not waking up anymore - or at least for a very long time which can not be considered sleeping.